# Get store item in Effect

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have a small Effect and I need to get the action data (nanoId) and I need to select data with this nanoId in store:

```
  @Effect()
  syncObj$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ObjActions.Actions.SYNC_NEW_OBJ),
    mergeMap(({nanoId, obj}) => {
      this.store.pipe(select(getObjByNanoId(nanoId), first())).subscribe(eObj => {
        // return [] <-- error if I try to return pipe result here and remove return below
      })
      return [] // <-- this is below return
    }
    )
  );
```

I thought of `withLatestFrom()` but it needs an additional pipe, as I understand.
My goal is to catch an object and nanoId from action, then select an object with nanoId in store (eOnj) and compare some of it's fields. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, you don't have to subscribe inside `withLatestFrom` since it requires an observable.

```
 @Effect()
  syncObj$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ObjActions.Actions.SYNC_NEW_OBJ),
    mergeMap(action => {
     
      return of(action).pipe(
        withLatestFrom(
          this.store.pipe(select(getObjByNanoId(nanoId)),
        )
      )
    }),
    mergeMap(([action, obj]) => {
      // code here
    })

  );
```

Comment: @Dmitry Welcome, glad to help